# gulp version append CSS, JS - AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

I have an application in AngularJS and would like to do version control of my JS and CSS files. I tried following the following tutorial more success not obvious.

https://github.com/SkeLLLa/gulp-version-append

Can anyone help? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this with a combination of two things:
`gulp-rename` and `gulp-inject`.

```
.pipe(rename('main-' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + '.min.js'))
...

and then


var target = gulp.src('./index.html');
var sources = gulp.src(['./dev/js/*.js'], {read: false});

return target.pipe(inject(sources, {relative: true}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
```

Take a look at those two libraries. Other options are not as practical.